# I have a TexturePacker file ccz ,but i have no plist files, how can i solve this?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Now I have a ccz file, but I have no plist files. How can I get a new plist file?

Can I generate a new plist file based on the given ccz file?

Answer (score 0):

No, you need the .tps source file or recreate the texture atlas.